# Converting dataframe of strings to categorical values

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I need to convert the entire data frame that consists of only `"0/1"`, `"1/1"`, and `"0/0"` to categorical values. I would like it to assign numbers  like this `0` to `"0/0"` `1` to `"1/1"` and `2` to `"0/1"`

The Data frame looks something like this, but much bigger:

[image]

I would like this to be done using apply
Result should look like this:

[image]

Here is the sample data frame

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(c("0/1", "1/1", "0/0"), 20,rep=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `apply` is not a must in the solution, I'll use `dplyr mutate()` and `case_when()`.

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), 
                     ~ case_when(.x == "1/1" ~ 1, 
                                 .x == "0/0" ~ 0, 
                                 .x == "0/1" ~ 2)))
```

### Output

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   1  2  2  2  0  1  2  0  1   0
2   2  2  0  0  0  0  2  2  0   1
3   1  1  0  1  0  2  0  1  0   2
4   1  2  1  0  1  1  1  2  2   2
5   2  0  1  0  0  2  2  0  1   2
6   2  2  0  0  0  1  1  2  2   2
7   2  0  0  2  2  1  0  0  0   2
8   1  2  2  2  2  0  1  2  2   2
9   1  0  1  2  2  0  1  0  1   0
10  1  0  1  2  1  1  0  2  1   2
11  1  0  0  0  2  2  1  0  1   0
12  2  1  2  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
13  0  2  0  2  2  1  1  1  2   2
14  0  0  0  1  2  0  0  0  1   1
15  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  2  1   2
16  0  0  0  2  0  1  2  0  2   2
17  0  2  2  2  0  2  1  2  0   0
18  2  1  2  2  0  1  1  2  2   0
19  0  2  2  2  0  2  1  2  2   0
20  2  0  2  2  0  1  1  0  0   1
```

### Input

```
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
1  1/1 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/0
2  0/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/1 0/0 1/1
3  1/1 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/1
4  1/1 0/1 1/1 0/0 1/1 1/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/1
5  0/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/1
6  0/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/1
7  0/1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/1 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1
8  1/1 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/1
9  1/1 0/0 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/0
10 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/1 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/1 1/1 0/1
11 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/1 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/0
12 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1
13 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/1 1/1 1/1 1/1 0/1 0/1
14 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1
15 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/1 1/1 0/1
16 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/1
17 0/0 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0
18 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0
19 0/0 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0
20 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/1 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0 1/1
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a named `vector` and use that to match and replace the values in the dataset

```
df[] <- setNames(c(0, 1, 2), c("0/0", "1/1", "0/1"))[as.matrix(df)]
```

-output

```
> df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   1  1  2  0  1  2  1  1  1   0
2   1  1  1  0  0  1  1  2  0   1
3   2  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2   2
4   2  1  1  0  0  0  0  2  2   0
5   0  2  0  2  2  2  0  0  0   2
6   0  0  0  2  0  1  1  0  0   0
7   2  1  1  0  1  0  2  2  0   1
8   2  0  2  1  2  2  2  1  2   0
9   0  1  1  0  1  2  2  1  2   0
10  2  0  2  1  1  1  1  2  2   1
11  2  2  0  1  1  0  0  1  2   0
12  2  1  1  1  1  2  0  1  0   1
13  0  1  2  2  2  1  2  2  1   1
14  0  0  0  0  1  2  2  1  0   1
15  2  2  0  2  1  0  0  0  1   2
16  0  2  2  0  2  1  1  2  2   0
17  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  2   1
18  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  2   0
19  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  2  0   1
20  1  0  2  1  0  0  2  1  0   0
> str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ X1 : num  1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 2 ...
 $ X2 : num  1 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ X3 : num  2 1 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ X4 : num  0 0 1 0 2 2 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ X5 : num  1 0 1 0 2 0 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ X6 : num  2 1 1 0 2 1 0 2 2 1 ...
 $ X7 : num  1 1 2 0 0 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ X8 : num  1 2 2 2 0 0 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ X9 : num  1 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 ...
 $ X10: num  0 1 2 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 ...
```

NOTE: The `sample` data created was without any `set.seed`, thus the values may be different